# Menu Selection not going back as per choice

Tags: powershell

I am having this below simple code to display menu in a script

```
        Write-Host "============= Main Category ================================="
            Write-Host " '1' InfoBlox"
            Write-Host " '2' Installation"
            Write-Host " '3' Active Directory"
            Write-Host " '4' LogInventory"
            Write-Host " '5' Configuration"
            Write-Host " '6' New Server Build CMDB Update "
            Write-Host " '7' for Exit"
        Write-Host "========================================================"
        $choice = Read-Host "`nEnter Choice"

if($choice -eq '1')
{
#Menu for choice 
    cls
    Write-Host "=============InfoBlox================================="
    Write-Host " '1' Add CNAME record"
    Write-Host " '2' Delete CNAME record"
    Write-Host " '3' Add A-record and PTR record"
    Write-Host " '4' Delete A-record and PTR record"
    Write-Host " '5' for Main Menu"
    Write-Host "========================================================"
    $subchoice = Read-Host "`nEnter Choice"
#code here
  if($subchoice -eq '5')
        {
        cls
        Write-Host "============= Main Category ================================="
            Write-Host " '1' InfoBlox"
            Write-Host " '2' Installation"
            Write-Host " '3' Active Directory"
            Write-Host " '4' LogInventory"
            Write-Host " '5' Configuration"
            Write-Host " '6' New Server Build CMDB Update "
            Write-Host " '7' for Exit"
        Write-Host "========================================================"
        $choice = Read-Host "`nEnter Choice"
}
if($choice -eq '2')
{
 #code here
}
if($choice -eq '3')
{
 #code here

}
```

Problem I am facing is when I am executing first time it is working fine. e.g. when I choose **1,2,3..**it is fine but when I am again going back from **3 to 1** as choice, the script is exiting and showing the powershell prompt.

Please let me know why it is happening.
I may be not able to explain properly. please let me know if any question.

Comment: It's happening because there's no more code to execute after the second main menu is displayed. You need to wrap your menus in individual functions and _return_ from those functions when exit/main menu is chosen, then wrap the whole thing in a loop (like a `while` loop for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) gave you the pointer in his helpful comment, each menu / option should have their own function or script block and the logic should be wrapped in an infinite loop that ends when the **Exit** option is chosen.

I have reduced the code for demonstration purposes.

```
function Menu {
    Write-Host " '1' Option 1"
    Write-Host " '2' Option 2"
    Write-Host " '3' for Exit"
}

function SelectSomething {
    Read-Host "`nEnter Choice"
}

function FirstOption {
    Write-Host " '1' Add CNAME record"
    Write-Host " '2' Delete CNAME record"
    Write-Host " '3' for Main Menu"
    SelectSomething
}

function SecondOption {
    Write-Host " '1' InfoBlox"
    Write-Host " '2' Installation"
    Write-Host " '3' for Main Menu"
    SelectSomething
}

$firstScriptblock = {
    switch(FirstOption) {
        1 { 'Option 1 - Add CNAME record' }
        2 { 'Option 2 - Delete CNAME record' }
        3 { return }
        Default { Write-Warning 'Invalid Selection' }
    }
    $Host.UI.ReadLine()
    & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock
}

$secondOption = {
    Write-Warning 'Not implemented! Back to Menu'
    $Host.UI.ReadLine()
}

:outer while($true) {
    Clear-Host
    Menu
    switch(SelectSomething) {
        1 { & $firstScriptblock }
        2 { & $secondOption }
        3 { break outer }
        Default { Write-Warning 'Invalid Selection' }
    }
}
```